# Latex cline won't work properly

Tags: latex, tabular

I would make the following table on latex with tabular.

```
 \begin{table}[]
    \centering 
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
     \hline
       \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}Ext Col 1} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}Ext Col 2} \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}Ext Row 1}                                                          \\ \hline
           & V11   & V12   &   \\ \cline{2-3}
           & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}Int Row 1}    &                          \\ \cline{2-3}
           & V21    & V22   &   \\ \hline
     \end{tabular}
   \end{table}
```

The problem here is that the cline command above "Int Row 1" does not display the line, resulting as shown in the following picture:

[image]

I have read similar issue on SO, but I can't figure out the problem. Many thanks.

Comment: Take a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270724/when-compiling-cline-between-the-coloured-cell-doesnt-appear

Comment: This is a viewer-related issue. Different zoom levels will show the `\cline`.

Comment: \hhline saves my day. Thanks  @BoboCarr

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the question linked by @Bobo Carr, replacing \cline with \hhline solves the issue.